# How to test where an imported static asset library fails on import

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, libraries

I have been trying to upload various bundled libraries to static resources to import them into a LWC component. I have been successful in doing this when using api version 39, but this fails on version 40+ due to locker service. My question is regarding how to find where this is failing as Salesforce throws a secure DOM event error and references the `<ltng:require>` script tag rather than the line that the library fails on?

Is there a stack trace of where the error is? If so, where can I find this?

I have already tried using Locker Console to test the libraries and this again does not give information regarding which line is failing due to locker service.